# Coercing string to int

Tags: r

Can anyone explain why the following happens in R:

```
> 0.0 < "14.9a"
[1] TRUE

> 2.03 < "14.9a"
[1] FALSE

> 10.11006 < "14.9a"
[1] TRUE
```

what happens when "14.9a" is coerced internally to an int? It can't just be ignoring non-numeric characters as the 2nd example shows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it's doing the opposite and converting the int to a string.

```
> "0.0" < "14.9a"
[1] TRUE

> "2.03" < "14.9a"
[1] FALSE

> "10.11006" < "14.9a"
[1] TRUE
```

From the help page:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

and also:

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the
>   strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see
>   locales. The collating sequence of locales such as en_US is normally
>   different from C (which should use ASCII) and can be surprising.
>   Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order ...

Comment: Correct, but note that the first case is `"0" < "14.9a"`, not `"0.0"`. It's pretty much the result of `as.character(0.0)`.

Answer (score 5):

As per `?"<"`:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of
>   precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and
>   raw.

The numeric values are therefore converted to strings, and the strings are then compared according to their lexicographic order. (I.e., "2" > "10")